# Conntrack: Why would a udp connection be destroyed before timeout

Tags: netfilter

I was trying to load balance udp connections across 2 servers. And I see that a single connection from client side creates 2 connections on server. So my load balancing doesn't work properly.

```
root@cfae:~# conntrack -E                       
    [NEW] udp      17 30 src=172.17.25.219 dst=172.17.29.133 sport=34087 dport=1194 [UNREPLIED] src=172.17.29.133 dst=172.17.25.219 sport=1194 dport=34087 mark=581
 [UPDATE] udp      17 30 src=172.17.25.219 dst=172.17.29.133 sport=34087 dport=1194 src=172.17.29.133 dst=172.17.25.219 sport=1194 dport=34087 mark=581
 [UPDATE] udp      17 180 src=172.17.25.219 dst=172.17.29.133 sport=34087 dport=1194 src=172.17.29.133 dst=172.17.25.219 sport=1194 dport=34087 [ASSURED] mark=581
[DESTROY] udp      17 src=172.17.25.219 dst=172.17.29.133 sport=34087 dport=1194 packets=29 bytes=4349 src=172.17.29.133 dst=172.17.25.219 sport=1194 dport=34087 packets=27 bytes=3596 [ASSURED] mark=581
    [NEW] udp      17 30 src=172.17.25.219 dst=172.17.29.133 sport=34087 dport=1194 [UNREPLIED] src=172.17.29.133 dst=172.17.25.219 sport=1194 dport=34087 mark=581
 [UPDATE] udp      17 30 src=172.17.25.219 dst=172.17.29.133 sport=34087 dport=1194 src=172.17.29.133 dst=172.17.25.219 sport=1194 dport=34087 mark=581
 [UPDATE] udp      17 180 src=172.17.25.219 dst=172.17.29.133 sport=34087 dport=1194 src=172.17.29.133 dst=172.17.25.219 sport=1194 dport=34087 [ASSURED] mark=581
```

All this happens within 10 secs, so there is no chance for a timeout. A udp connection is being destroyed before timeout. Why would that happen?

I ran tcpdump, I see no ICMP unreachable packets, or any other suspicious looking packets.

Comment: There's no such thing as UDP connection. With UDP packet is simply deployed to the target without any connections made between the client and the server.

Comment: True, but netfilter has the concept of 'UDP stream', the state 'ASSURED' is supposed to indicate that netfilter detected a udp stream. And the timeout is also changed, as you can see, from 30 to 180 secs. But immediately after that the 'stream' is destroyed. I see that a particular packet must have caused it, but I can't understand which one.